# Setting Reminders and Expirations for envelope (embedded signing)

Tags: docusignapi

We have integrated Docusign in our app.
I am using docusign sdk to set reminders to bulk envelopes.
The recipients do not have docusign accounts. They are basically following an embedded signing flow (meaning they don't receive emails to sign documents).
Unfortunately they are not receiving any reminders.

Will they get reminder emails ? (I am asking because since they follow an embedded flow)
I have checked the notification status of the envelopes sent there it shows that reminders have been set.

{
"reminders": {
"reminderEnabled": "true",
"reminderDelay": "1",
"reminderFrequency": "2"
},
"expirations": {
"expireEnabled": "true",
"expireAfter": "120",
"expireWarn": "0"
}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Embedded recipients](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded/) don't get emails.
It doesn't make sense to do so, because there's no way they can get back to the signing experience which is embedded inside your application.

If you need this, they have to be switched from embedded back to regular signers ([remote signing](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-remote/)) that get emails from DocuSign.
Only then they'll receive reminders.